# How to render Result in these each object

Tags: reactjs

** Problem:**

I have an object like this.
[image]

I want to render each object Records in a Table. My code is like this.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { offenceActions } from "../../../actions";
import { Card, CardBody, Table } from "reactstrap";

class Offencelist extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      offences: []
    };

    this.renderOffences = this.renderOffences.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getOffence();
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.offences !== prevState.offences) {
      return { offences: nextProps.offences };
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  renderOffences() {
    var offences = this.state.offences;
    console.log(offences)
    if (Object.keys(offences) !== 0) {
      return Object.values(offences).map((el, index) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <tr key={index}>
          <td align="center">{el.id}</td>
            <td align="center">{el.title}</td>
            <td align="center">{el.description}</td>
            <td align="center">{el.penaltyMarks}</td>
            <td align="center">{el.fine}</td>
            <td align="center">{el.finecount}</td>
          </tr>
        </React.Fragment>
      ));
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Card>
            <CardBody>
              <Table hover bordered striped responsive size="sm">
                <thead className="officer-list-table-header">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Offence ID</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Penalty Marks</th>
                    <th>Fine Count</th>
                    <th>Fine</th>
                    <th />
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>{this.renderOffences()}</tbody>
              </Table>
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log(state);
  return {
    offences: state.offence.offences
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  offenceActions
)(Offencelist);
```

But this not rendering the Records as table rows. Can someone help me with this Thank you?. I search for it on the Internet and Tried a lot to find a solution for this issue. And Even search on the stack overflow to find a similar question regarding this issue. But I was not able to find a solution in there.

Comment: can you make a example on codesandbox ? I think `offences` is array not object. So `Object.values(offences).map` is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:-

1) You are not returning anything from `map`

2) You are iterating over offences only but you should be actually iterating over `offences.Record`.

```
  return Object.values(offences).map((el, index) => {
    el = el.Record // 2) iterate over Record
    return ( // 1) Return from map
      <React.Fragment>
```

Here is the working code (adding dummy data) and working [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-wiles-2cv63):-

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Card, CardBody, Table } from "reactstrap";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    offences: [
      {
        key: "F001",
        Record: {
          description: "Speeding over area",
          docType: "offence",
          fine: "100",
          finecount: 0,
          id: "F001",
          penaltyMarks: "High speed",
          title: "high Speed"
        }
      },
      {
        key: "F002",
        Record: {
          description: "Speeding over area",
          docType: "offence",
          fine: "100",
          finecount: 0,
          id: "F002",
          penaltyMarks: "High speed",
          title: "high Speed"
        }
      },
      {
        key: "F003",
        Record: {
          description: "Speeding over area",
          docType: "offence",
          fine: "100",
          finecount: 0,
          id: "F003",
          penaltyMarks: "High speed",
          title: "high Speed"
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  renderOffences = () => {
    var offences = this.state.offences;
    if (Object.keys(offences) !== 0) {
      return Object.values(offences).map((el, index) => {
        el = el.Record
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <tr key={index}>
              <td align="center">{el.id}</td>
              <td align="center">{el.title}</td>
              <td align="center">{el.description}</td>
              <td align="center">{el.penaltyMarks}</td>
              <td align="center">{el.fine}</td>
              <td align="center">{el.finecount}</td>
            </tr>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Card>
            <CardBody>
              <Table hover bordered striped responsive size="sm">
                <thead className="officer-list-table-header">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Offence ID</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Penalty Marks</th>
                    <th>Fine Count</th>
                    <th>Fine</th>
                    <th />
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>{this.renderOffences()}</tbody>
              </Table>
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Hope it helps!!!